# OpenSSL: create self signed certificate for Chrome that works on nginx hosted site

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to configure a nginx web site so that it uses a self-signed certificate and I'm unable to configure Chrome so that it considers the self-signed certificate valid.

Let me give you more info about what I'm doing. I've started  by creating the following cnf file for configuring the self-signed certificate:

```
[req]
default_bits       = 2048
default_md         = sha256
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions    = x509_ext
prompt             = no

[req_distinguished_name]
C  = PT
ST = MD
L  = Funchal
O  = luisabreu
CN = Testing certificates

[x509_ext]
subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid, issuer
basicConstraints        = CA:TRUE
keyUsage               = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, digitalSignature, nonRepudiation
extendedKeyUsage       = serverAuth, clientAuth
subjectAltName         = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = testing.pt
IP.1  = 10.50.150.130
```

Since I'd like my certificate to be considered a CA root so that it could be imported to Chrome, I've set it on the `basicConstraints` field.

The certificate keys are generated by running the following command (assuming that the configuration file is called certificate.cnf):

```
openssl req -config certificate.cnf -new -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout ssl.key -out ssl.crt -days 10500
```

Then, I copy the CA to the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` folder and run the `update-ca-certificates` command:

```
sudo cp ssl.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

sudo update-ca-certificates
```

After updating the machine's CA store, I copy the public and private keys to the `/etc/ssl/certs/`  and `/etc/ssl/private/` folder:

```
sudo cp ssl.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
sudo cp ssl.key /etc/ssl/private/
```

Then I've updated the `default.conf` file of the nginx so  that it uses these files:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl.key;
```

And I've reloaded the config by running the following:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Then, I've went into the chrome certificate store (chrome://settings/certificates) and I've imported the `ssl.crt` file. It does get imported without errors, but it does not show any info on the "This certificate has been verified for the following usages:"

[image: CA certificate information shown on Chrome]

Unfortunately, it seems like I'm still missing something because Chrome still complains about the certificate:

[image: Invalid certificate message]

Can anyone help? Did I miss anything on the conf file used for generating the certificate? Do I need to generate a separate CA for signing the site's certificate? I've tried using the certificate on a windows machine and it worked (putting in on the Personal and Trusted CA fodlers of the Local machine's certificate store...)

Thanks.